# How to put my DB SQLite in Android app?

Tags: android

Hello everyone first of all.
I am making an application for android, which I need to have a database for information.
The database management computer mailbox.
What I need is to take that database and included in the application for android'S SELECT generally.

I've been testing it on [this website](http://es.wikicode.org/index.php/Usar_nuestra_propia_sqlite_en_Android), but I can not get it to work. I do not think either the DB copy to memory, and then to perform the query, she says she can not find the table.
I have been debugged and saw that even the open works, but something strange happens ...

If you have some method or way of doing this, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these resources

[This tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) by Lars Vogel

[This reference article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) from Android website

Answer (score 1):

Puit it in your assets directory in your apk, and on first use copy to "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/" directory.  Here is SO discussion on this topic. [database in assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)